# Inter rater agreement computation

Tags: r, statistics

In my study we let 10 human raters rate 2 books on 3 aspects (accuracy, clarity, simplicity). I am trying to calculate the inter-rater agreement but facing issue which I am unable to resolve. I am new to R programming. here is a reproducible example and i request your help!

```
data <- data.frame(
  rater = c("rater-1", "rater-2", "rater-3"),
  clarity = c(3, 4,4),
  simplicity = c(5, 5,4),
  accuracy = c(2, 4,5)
)

# Convert the data frame to a matrix
ratings <- as.matrix(data[, -1])

# Calculate Fleiss' Kappa for each dimension
clarity_kappa <- kappa2(ratings[, "clarity"])
simplicity_kappa <- kappa2(ratings[, "simplicity"])
accuracy_kappa <- kappa2(ratings[, "accuracy"])

# Output the results
print(paste("Clarity Kappa:", clarity_kappa$value))
print(paste("Simplicity Kappa:", simplicity_kappa$value))
print(paste("Accuracy Kappa:", accuracy_kappa$value))
```

Error:

> clarity_kappa <- kappa2(ratings[, "clarity"]) Error in ratings[, 2]: subscript out of bounds

Comment: What package is `kappa2()` from?

Comment: Hi Azor. It is library(icc)

Comment: Looks like `icc` isn't available for my version of R

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- its not from a icc (which I dont think exists, though ICC does), its from `library(irr)`

Comment: @miki `kappa2` is [explicitly for 2 raters](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/irr/html/kappa2.html), you have 3

Comment: thanks jpsmith. How can i compute the ICC in this case? can you guide me pls. thanks! :)